# android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions .How to fix it

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragmentmanager

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:770)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1682)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:541)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6946)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Google console giving me crash report for `Fragment manager java.lang.NullPointerException: at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run()`. But I can't figure it out why its happening. Because it may be device specific issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem.I was using below code on `backpress` of hosted activity.Its a device specific issue happening with Android 5.1, 6.0 and 7.0.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        for(Fragment fragment:getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        }
        this.finish();
    }
```